# Chrome DevTools - link/jump to source file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

So lets assume we have a page with list of javascript errors displayed. For each error I see filename, line and column.

Is it possible to make a link on every error that would open up devTools and jump to specified source file directly to that line & column?

Comment: If you click the linenumber, it should jump to that line in your source files.

Comment: Errors are not displayed in devTools but are loaded as text on site.

Comment: No, devtools cannot be automated in such a sophisticated way. Please file a bug at http://crbug.com/new if you desperately need something like this.